# Is there a way to require a header in an ASP.NET API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```
public class GroupsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<GroupsController> _logger;

    public GroupsController(ILogger<GroupsController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;

        string auth = Request.Headers["authorization"];

        if (auth is null) 
             throw new Exception("Missing auth token");
    }

    [HttpGet("/[controller]/allGroups")]
    public List<Group> GetGroups()
    {
        DbContext dbContext = new DbContext();

        List<Group> groups = dbContext.Groups.ToList();

        return groups;
    }
}
```

I'm looking to require a authorization header only for this controller, but `Request` is not possible on the constructor and I don't want to add a auth check on every method on the controller.

Is there a way to check this header on all routes on this controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom attribute that validates headers and put it on the action or controller for which you want to validate headers. like this:

```
public class RequiredHeaderAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    private readonly string _requiredHeader;

    public RequiredHeaderAttribute(string requiredHeader)
    {
        _requiredHeader = requiredHeader;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        //
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.
            TryGetValue(_requiredHeader, out _))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Missing Header Exception: {_requiredHeader}");
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[RequiredHeader("HeaderName")] //<==NOTE THIS
[HttpGet("/[controller]/allGroups")]
public List<Group> GetGroups()
{
    DbContext dbContext = new DbContext();

    List<Group> groups = dbContext.Groups.ToList();

    return groups;
}
```

Or

```
[RequiredHeader("HeaderName")]
public class GroupsController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Another way is register `RequiredHeader` as global filters.